# Cálculos erróneos de tangente y volumen de una esfera

Tags: python

Cuando aplico

```
angulo = math.radians(180)
tang = math.tan(angulo)
```

me da como resultado -1.22464679915e-16 y debería darme 1.33869021

En cambio para:

```
angulo = math.radians(0)
tang = math.tan(angulo)
```

Me da bien el resultado, 0.

¿A que se debe esto? Me está pasando con algunos cálculos de areas y volúmenes y  no lo entiendo.

Otro ejemplo, volumen de una esfera. Su fórmula es V=4/3*Pi*r^3. Yo hago:

```
vol_esf = (4/3) * math.pi * 1,2**3
```

Y en vez de darme 7.2382, me da 5.4288

No veo el problema donde está. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

¡Salud y gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La tangente de 180º [es cero](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan(pi)), igual que la de 0º. Por tanto Python te está dando bien el resultado (salvo el error de redondeo atribuíble al uso de números de coma flotante). No sé de dónde sacas que habría de ser 1.33869021

En cuanto a la otra duda, tiene toda la pinta de que estás usando Python2. En Python2, el operador `/` hace la división entera cuando lo que aparece a ambos lados es entero. Por tanto `4/3` no da como resultado 1.33333333 sino 1 (la división entera trunca, es decir, elimina los decimales).

Para evitarlo tienes que hacer que los operandos de `/` sean de punto flotante (al menos uno de ellos). Es decir, escribe `4.0/3.0` en lugar de `4/3`. Por cierto que el código que pegaste tiene otro error, pues la separación de decimales es el punto y no la coma. Intepreto que ha sido un error al transcribirlo pero que en tu programa estaba bien. Esta sería por tanto la fórmula correcta:

```
vol_esf = (4.0/3.0) * math.pi * 1.2**3
```

En python3 no tienes ese problema pues `/` siempre hace división de punto flotante independientemente de si sus operandos son enteros o no.

Answer (score 0):

180 radianes no es lo mismo que 180 grados, por lo que tu error es que debería ser

`angulo = math.radians(1)`

en vez de

`angulo = math.radians(180)`

Es decir, un radian (pi), y no 180 radianes.

Comment: Me he explicado mal, voy a editar la pregunta. El problema no es de radianes o grados, es que me da otros números